# how to create second surface in Android NDK

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

I create surface with following code:

```
const EGLint attrs[] = {
 EGL_LEVEL, 0,
 EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
 EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
 EGL_NATIVE_RENDERABLE, EGL_FALSE,
 EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, EGL_DONT_CARE,
 EGL_NONE
};
FDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
EGLint major = 0;
EGLint minor = 0;
if (!eglInitialize(FDisplay, &major, &minor))
    return;
EGLConfig eglConfig;
// Obtain the first configuration with a depth buffer
EGLint numConfig = 0;
if (!eglChooseConfig(FDisplay, attrs, &eglConfig, 1, &numConfig))
    return;

    FSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(FDisplay, eglConfig,  
                single_native_window: FNativeHwnd, NULL);
```

The problem is that eglCreateWindowSurface is not successful, returns EGL_NO_SURFACE when calling for second surface. I call it passing FDisplay which is same display as was used for the first surface. What i do wrong? Maybe there is another approach to create second surface?

Comment: Probably you should pass handle to another native window, that will represent second surface.

Comment: ok, if i can create just one surface per native window, then my next question: how can i create invisible second native window(i need second surface to do GPU accelerated math). Or at least where they define in Android specs that only one surface can be created per native window?